# Pass a bash variable to a perl command

Tags: bash, image, perl, rename, subdirectory

I'm trying to rename a folder with the following structure:

```
xxx_name_surname/
├── whatever.jpg
├── foobar.jpg
├ [...]
├── barfoo.jpg
└── full
    ├── whatever.jpg
    ├── foobar.jpg
    ├ [...]
    ├── barfoo.jpg
```

in something like:

```
xxx_name_surname/
├── 001_name_surname.jpg
├── 001_name_surname.jpg
├ [...]
├── 011_name_surname.jpg
└── full
    ├── 001_name_surname.jpg
    ├── 002_name_surname.jpg
    ├ [...]
    ├── 011_name_surname.jpg
```

I'm using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for d in *; 
    do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
            cd $d;

            folder_name=${PWD##*/}
            image_name=${folder_name:4}
            echo Current dir is:
            echo $current_dir
            echo "Rename and sanitize image in folder ..."
            export $image_name

            rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . '_' . $_' *.jpg

            echo
            echo "Creating folder" $d"/full ..."
            mkdir full
            echo "Adding padding to image ..."
            mogrify -path full -background white -gravity center -resize 1920x1080\> -extent 1920x1080 *.jpg
            cd ..
            echo
        fi
done

echo "Done."
```

The script I made is trying to:

- parse the folder structure
- get the parent folder name (without the xxx number)
- rename and sanitize the file name (rename is a Perl script -> refer to http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/)
- create a full version of the images with mogrify and put the output in the full folder.

My problem is related to the rename command:

```
rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . '_' . $_' *.jpg
```

According to the [manual page](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) is it possibile to rename the file with a counter as prefix.
I understand that is a syntax problem related to pass a bash argument to a perl script. I've also found same answer here on stackexchange but I cannot resolve myself as I'm not a perl expert.

Then I'm aware that the script is very easy, but I'd like to ask if you have suggestions in order to get the same results – with bash, command line — but in a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: This is bash, not Perl. What kind of Perl script are you referring to? Also, your example tree output shows a file name twice.

Comment: I'm referring to rename command, that is written in Perl http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/

Comment: I think the `-N ...001` is nothing special. It's not any magic, it's just a string. In the `rename` program it parses that string. I think you don't need the second zero, just doing `-N ...01` would be enough to get the numbers to be as wide as nedeed and zero-padded. Have you run your program with `-n` to do a a dry run and see what happens?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? What's the problem? Your title sounds like you think you know what your problem is, but I think you're not telling us everything (possibly because you don't know which parts are relevant). Please include any error message you are getting, or show us how the output is different from what you're expecting.

Comment: The problem is that with the command 

`rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . '_' . $_' *.jpg` 

I'm not able to concatenate the counter generate by the -N in the perl command (rename) with the name taken in my bash script with the variable $image_name (bash environment). 

According to the man page rename should use -e to print the filename. From the manual page, the tutorial show this as example: 

`rename -N ...01 -X -e '$_ = "File-$N"' *`
 
I'd like to change this pattern in order to print something like:

`001_name_surname.jpg`

Comment: Oh. Ok. It looks like the `-e` is equivalent to `perl -e`, which runs stuff as perl code, like an _eval_. You mixed up the quotes. `-e '$_ = "$N" . "_" . $_'` should do it. Or `-e '$_ = "${N}_$_"'` if you want it to be less readable.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, but this doesn't solve :( Is there a way to use the `$image_name` in the rename parameters? Something like: `-e '$_ = "$N" . "_" . $image_name'`? I've also tried `-e '$_ = "$N" . "_" . $ENV{$image_name}'` without success.

Comment: That should be in `$ENV{image_name}`. Something like `-e '$_ = $N . "_" . $ENV{image_name}'`. (You don't need double quotes `""` around the `$N`, I didn't pay attention above.)

Comment: With `rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . "_" . $ENV{image_name}' *.jpg
` I get this errror: `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 2) line 1.`

Comment: So the `export`ed bash var doesn't end up in Perl's env. Hmm. But what do you expect that to do anyway? `$_` has the filename, and you're supposed to change it. It looks like the shell var `$image_name` is the same file name. Why do you want to append the old file name to the new file name? Leave that out and try to run it with `-n` for a dry run.

Comment: I'm trying to use the folder name the is in the format xxx_name_surname to rename the images in the folder. So my script get the folder name, stores in the `$image_name` variable and I'd like to use it as parameter in the rename command. If you use the syntex you have previously suggested with a ENV variable like $ENV{LOGNAME} it works. So the problems is related in my bash script: I have to store $image_name in something like $ENV{image_name} but I tried and doesn't work.

Comment: What should work is setting it explicitly in the environment of the call to `rename` like this. `FOO=$image_name rename ... -e '$ENV{FOO}'`

Comment: I've got a solution:

`     IMAGENAME=$(echo $image_name)
     export IMAGENAME
     rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . "_" . $ENV{IMAGENAME}' *.jpg`

Comment: It seems overly complicated. You could probably build that whole string for the `-e` in bash and then put it there too. But my bash is not sufficient to do that. Post your own solution as an answer here please.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

This solved my question:

```
    IMAGENAME=$(echo $image_name)
    export IMAGENAME
    rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . "_" . $ENV{IMAGENAME}' *.jpg
```

so the final bash script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in *; 
    do
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
            cd $d;
            folder_name=${PWD##*/}
            image_name=${folder_name:4}

            echo "Rename and sanitize image in folder ..."
            IMAGENAME=$(echo $image_name)
            export IMAGENAME
            rename -f -N ...001 -X -e '$_ = $N . "_" . $ENV{IMAGENAME}' *.jpg
            echo "Creating folder" $d"/full ..."
            mkdir full
            echo "Adding padding to image ..."
            mogrify -path full -background white -gravity center -resize 1920x1080\> -extent 1920x1080 *.jpg
            cd ..
            echo
        fi
done
echo "Done."
```

**NOTE**

As you can see the script is not the best solution, but is doing the job.